# One of my dual royal pistols becomes a scottish flintlock after fast traveling

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I got my two royal pistols the double barrel pistols and every time I fast travel anywhere it always changes one of my pistols to the Scottish flintlock pistols but it keeps my other royal pistol how can I keep both of them

Comment: I changed your tags, because the question is about the game, not the game system. The game system tags should only be used if it is a question about the system itself, or if you have a system-specific question related to a game.

Comment: I used to have this issue on PC when the game came out. Re-played the game recently and didn't encounter this issue. Good luck figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. It happened on consoles and even on pc.

It's just a bug that Ubisoft has to patch. But since it's not game breaking it isn't that much of a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. It's easy,but it only works on the royal pistol. This worked for all my friends; you just have to go to the manor and select the royal pistol(when you are changing your pistol you should be in the assassin white outfit). Immediately after changing go and change your outfit to achilles first assassin outfit. When you equipped the outfit just immediately shutdown your console/pc and restart. This worked for all my friends who were using pc and ps3. Enjoy the game.